# how to use custom JS in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular, typescript

**is it possible to use my own custom js in the site?**. like.. i have a menu in app.component.html. that visibility is managed by the custom js

index.html

```
       <!-- App js -->
<head>
    <script src="app/assets/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="app/assets/js/app.js"></script> 
</head>
```

app.component.html

```
                <!-- Mobile menu toggle-->
                <a class="navbar-toggle">
                    <div class="lines"><span></span></div>
                </a>
                <!-- End mobile menu toggle-->
```

app.js

```
 console.log ( 'Js Loaded' );
!function($) {
    "use strict";

    var Navbar = function() {};

    //topbar
    Navbar.prototype.init = function () {
      //toggle

      $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('navbar click');
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#navigation').slideToggle(400);
      });     
    },
    //init
    $.Navbar = new Navbar, $.Navbar.Constructor = Navbar
}
```

Will it work in Angular2 Typescript. **Am trying to migrate the angular 1 to 2. its working perfectly in Angular1** . how to do in Angular2

Comment: typescript is a superset of javascript so this should work

Comment: @madalinivascu ya but click function is not working, i can see JS loaded via console logs. is there any other way i can see logs for the click event?

Comment: yes you can put a console log inside the click event, i suggest you better go with converting your custom js to angular